Conan - Cannot install Boost with Conan in Visual Studio 2022
I recently updated to Visual Studio 2022. As I have several projects in which dependencies are managed by Conan, I also installed and configured Conan 2, as well as the Conan Extension for Visual Studio.
However the build fails on Boost, and I cannot figure out why.
Below is a part of my build log (just what seem most relevant for me, you can find the complete log at this link: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/24319):
Changes detected, executing conan install...
Arguments for conan install:  . -pr:h .conan/Debug_x64 -pr:b default --build missing

======== Input profiles ========
Profile host:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Debug
compiler=msvc
compiler.cppstd=20
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.runtime_type=Debug
compiler.version=193
os=Windows
[options]
boost/*:without_python=True
libcurl/*:with_ssl=schannel
libraw/*:with_jasper=False
zlib/*:shared=False

Profile build:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
os=Windows

...

-------- Installing package boost/1.85.0 (10 of 16) --------

...

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : building
    - charconv                 : building
    - chrono                   : building
    - cobalt                   : building
    - container                : building
    - context                  : building
    - contract                 : building
    - coroutine                : building
    - date_time                : building
    - exception                : building
    - fiber                    : not building
    - filesystem               : building
    - graph                    : building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - headers                  : not building
    - iostreams                : building
    - json                     : building
    - locale                   : building
    - log                      : building
    - math                     : building
    - mpi                      : not building
    - nowide                   : building
    - program_options          : building
    - python                   : not building
    - random                   : building
    - regex                    : building
    - serialization            : building
    - stacktrace               : building
    - system                   : building
    - test                     : building
    - thread                   : building
    - timer                    : building
    - type_erasure             : building
    - url                      : building
    - wave                     : building

...

boost/1.85.0 : error : 
Package '33017ceeaac67a9ba299b4855ce218a9436f8362' build failed
boost/1.85.0: WARN: Build folder C:\Users\<my_account>\.conan2\p\b\boost2a738f870ecbe\b\build-debug
EXEC : error : boost/1.85.0: Error in build() method, line 1130
    self.run(full_command)
    ConanException: Error 1 while executing
EXEC : error : Conan installation failed. Please check the console output to troubleshoot issues.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(156,5): error MSB3073: The command "
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(156,5): error MSB3073: set CONAN_BUILD_CONFIG="Debug_x64" && "C:\MyRepos\vs2022_dev\MyProject\.conan\conan_install.bat" . -pr:h=.conan/Debug_x64 -pr:b=default --build=missing
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(156,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix that?

Boost didnt have support for the last VS 17.10 update. It had to bump its build system B2 to the last version, this was done some hours ago in https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/pull/24273. Please try to remove your cache files with conan remove "*" -c and start again, and see if it is fixed. If not please create a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

@drodri Thank you for the notification. Indeed after cleaning my cache and rebuild all the dependencies, Boost was installed successfully. So on my side the issue was resolved

Good, thanks for the feedback @Jean-Milost Reymond
